# scrapy shell url return SyntaxError in iPython notebook

Tags: scrapy, ipython

In windows power shell ,I can run  `scrapy shell 'http://www.hao123.com'`,
[scrapy shell 'http://www.hao123.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q2O3.png)
I can run `ipython`
I can run `ipython` but not `scrapy shell 'http://www.hao123.com'`
[ipython then scrapy shell 'http://www.hao123.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh9yc.png)
In ipython notebook,I can't run `scrapy shell 'http://www.hao123.com'`also

```
scrapy shell 'http://www.hao123.com'
  File "<ipython-input-3-be4048c8f90b>", line 1
    scrapy shell 'http://www.hao123.com'
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Ipython is installed by anaconda,scrapy is installed by pip,anaconda and pip is in different file.
Please help me!

Comment: You should provide more information about what you are doing and where (context).  All we know is that it isn't `windows shell`.

Comment: @Cireo. Thanks,I edit it again

Answer (score 0):

That's not a feature you can have in ipython. `scrapy shell` is a command, it's own application completely separate from `ipython`.

However, there are two things you can do:

If you have a Spider and Response objects from somewhere you can simply use `scrapy.shell.inspect_repsonse`

```
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
# You need a scrapy spider object that has crawler instance attached to it
some_spider = Spider()  
# you need response object
some_response = Response()  
inspect_response(some_spider, some_response)
# new ipython shell will be embedded, like one from scrapy shell command
```

Otherwise you can spawn a subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('scrapy shell http://stackoverflow.com', shell=True)
# new ipython shell will be embedded, like one from scrapy shell command
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,but I see the document says ipython supports scrapy shell.This is the site:https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html

Comment: @Kyan yes scrapy does support __embedding__ of multiple shells like bpython, ipython and default python shells. However what you want here is ipython having some custom syntax for launching scrapy shell? that does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Anaconda on windows 7 . 
Follow:  environment --> root --> Open terminal. Then you can write:

> scrapy shell 'http://www.hao123.com'